# Bootstrap X-Editable mapping to JSF Managed Bean

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, jsf-2, x-editable

Have been trying to get Bootstrap's X-Editable type to work in with JSF2.2 for improving the UX with a profile form. There doesn't seem to be much on this using X-Editables with JSF yet? The user's profile page will allow viewing/editing inline by clicking on an entry. On submission of a change the Bean should be persisted/updated.

The method I've gotten working is a bit cumbersome as it requires JS for each field and am looking for improvements/best practice.

- Is it possible to make a generic JS call for each field submission
  rather than individual ones?
- In addition, doing it this way bypasses
  the built in JSF form validation.
- Thoughts for improvement please?

Firstly the Managed Bean:

```
@ViewScoped
public class UserController implements Serializable {

    private User user;

    public UserController() { }

    public String update() {
        try {
            getFacade().edit(user);
        } (Exception e) { //Exception handling }
    }

    //Getters/setters etc.

}
```

The XHTML snippet with hidden Save button that the JS triggers on submission of a change:

```
<h:form id="mainForm">
    <div>
        <h:inputHidden value="#{userController.user.alias}" id="aliasHidden"/>
        <span class="editable" id="alias">#{userController.user.alias}</span>
    </div>
    <div>
        //Other "editable" fields
    </div>
    <h:commandButton id="saveButton" value="Save" action="#{userController.update}" style="display:none;">
        <f:ajax execute="@form" />
    </h:commandButton>
</h:form>
```

Then the JS:

```
jquery(function ($){
    //The generic save on submission of change to persist the bean
    $('.editable').on('save', function (e, params) {
        document.getElementById('mainForm:saveButton').click();
    });
    //Render the editable and resulting function to move the editable entry into the bean prior to persist
    $('#alias').editable({
        type: 'text',
        name: 'alias',
        url: function (params) {
            $('input[id*=aliasHidden]').val(params.value);
        }
    });
}
```